# Redirect 301 specific folders back to Root domain: How to setup in .Htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, directory

Dear folks, How to setup a proper APACHE rule  in .Htaccess on shared hosting to get this Condition and Rule working:

```
RewriteCond ...
RewriteRule ...
```

*Where...*

**Condition =** If the browser url contains any directory equal to `(one|two|three)` which are forbidden directories, then...

**Rule =** do not load any pages there, instead: 301 to the relative root `/`   ... that way loading effectively the main domain name, whatever that domain may be. So: once again: I don't want to to use hard coded absolute domain name, just relative root (or erase the entire relative url that would be same as going to the root right?)

Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/one/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/two/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/three/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

...should do it.

Comment: Thanks @middaparka, but... I explicitely do not want to hard code an absolute url path, as am using several aliases. So want to respect the domain, whatever it was, and just go to the root. Would that be possible? Thank you.

Comment: @Sam Just replace the `http://www.yourdomain.com` with `/` and all should be well.

Comment: thanks! is there any way to combine the folders into a `( | OR | OR | )` e.g. (one|two|three) fashion?   By the way I see that when I add [OR] your nice code does work!!!